# Trying to return values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two MYSQL tables for card games management:

The first one, Matches table:

```
ID   ATeam BTeam Player1 Player2
001  T1    T2    1       2
```

there's another table (Players table) with player's ID and names:

```
ID Name
1  Dave
2  Martin
```

What I'm trying to do is with one MYSQL SELECT get all matches where player1 (for instance ID player=1) is currently appointed to, and return player's name, not the ID.
In order to achieve that, I need to query players table but I'm not sure what to use: INNER JOIN perhaps??

The result should be:

```
001  T1  T2  Dave  Martin
```

Instead of

```
001 T1  T2  1  2
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That a simple join query:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.ATeam, m.BTeam, p1.Name, p2.Name
FROM Matches AS m
JOIN Players AS p1 ON m.Player1 = p1.ID
JOIN Players AS p2 ON m.Player2 = p2.ID
WHERE m.Player1 = ?
```

Comment: May be left join would be a better idea in case one of `Player1` or `Player2` value is missing on `Matches`

Comment: wow it worked, sorry I know it's a simple question but I'm not familiar with SQL...

Comment: I needed to use Left join, but I just copied your query and it's returning sometimes player1 name on player2 field and vice versa?

Comment: sorry again... I had data mixed on table... Now it works great thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
select m.id, m.ATeam, m.BTeam, p1.name, p2.name from matches m inner join player p1 inner join player p2 on m.player1 = p1.id and m.player2 = p2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Giorgos Betsos answer but use left join

```
SELECT Matches.ID, Matches.ATeam, Matches.BTeam, p1.Name, p2.Name
FROM Matches
LEFT JOIN Players AS p1 ON (Matches.Player1 = p1.ID)
LEFT JOIN Players AS p2 ON (Matches.Player2 = p2.ID)
```